# Extracting info from one worksheet to insert in another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook to track the progress of qualifications. Each qualification is a worksheet with each column representing a section. If the section is marked X, it is completed. The last column of each worksheet is the percentage completed.
I need to look through column L (percentage) and pull values between 0.75 to 0.99 and the related name from column A, on to a different sheet titled summary. These values should be input into their respective columns on the example below (Name, Percentage).
I also need to list the sections each name is missing in the last column on the summary page (Sections missing).

I tried an

```
=IF(AND(0.75\<=QualPercentWS,0.99\>=QualPercentWS),NameCoulmn,"")
```

but this only does the row selected. I need it to go through the whole column and only display those between 75% and 99%.

This is an example of the sheet for a qualification.

[image]

On a separate sheet, I need these details from the qualification sheets that fulfill the above requirements. Please and thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the desired output. Then it might be easier to help you. Maybe reading [ask] could help you to enhance your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.